# How do I display validation error in Slack modal

Tags: javascript, response, slack-api

I am building a [modal](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals) in slack. The idea is to validate the user's input upon finishing editing an
`input` element (without submitting and closing the view).

[Slack says I can do it](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#displaying_errors) by replying to playload with `response_action` and `error object`. I've been trying to do this but I still can't display the error. How do I respond to the payload?

I'm completely new at this, so please talk to me as to a newbie.

Here's my code for validating the error:

```
app.action("dispatch_1", async ({ action, ack, respond }) => {
  await ack();

  var text = action.value;

  try {
    if (/^(ftp|http|https):\/\/[^ "]+$/.test(text)) {
      await ack();
      console.log("Success")
    } else {
      await ack({
  "response_action": "errors",
  "errors": {
    "dispatch_1": "Sorry, this isn't a valid input"
  }
});
      console.log("Fail")
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are already acking right away. Remove the very first ack, to allow your inputs to be validated.